# gps receiver and windows phone 8 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm debugging some windows phone 8 location tracking application and I want to purchase gps-receiver and connect it to my notebook for reality test of application with real location data. Will it work? Can the application running in the emulator get these real data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the emulator can communicate with the GPS receiver. You can, however, use the emulator location data to simulator it. Take a look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202933(v=vs.105).aspx) guide to learn more.

Comment: It's a pity. I know about gps simulator, but unfortunately it can't reproduce real situations like loosing satellites signals when i'm driving in tunnel for example, timeouts when searching satellites, switching between cellular/wifi and satellite data and so on.